# how can I resize gif with custom height and width in android?

Tags: android, imageview, gif, android-ion

I am using Koush/Ion library to load gif from internet into imageview but I cannot resize the gifs aspectly, upon calling resize function, gif becomes still

so my question is, is there any way I can resize gif aspectly in android ?

here's my calculation to get aspect height and width of image if that helps

```
final int newWidth = deviceWidth;
final int newHeight = (int) ((int) newWidth * (imageHeight / imageWidth));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I finally found the solution,
First scale image with FIT_XY and then set 'newHeight' as the height of image view

```
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
```

Code Snippet

```
Ion.with(imageView)
    .animateGif(AnimateGifMode.ANIMATE)
    .load(imgUrl)
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback < ImageView > () {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception arg0,
    ImageView arg1) {

        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {

                imageView.getViewTreeObserver()
                    .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize a gif in android programatically. When you do so the gif does not animate as it becomes a normal Image. In order to resize the gif and animate it, the only suggestion that I can give you is to use online resizing tools like

- [EzGif](http://ezgif.com/resize)
- [GifMaker](http://gifmaker.me/resizer/)
- [Picason](http://picasion.com/resize-gif/)

Later save the resized gif in your `assets` folder and then call that using the `Ion library` which you use like this

```
Ion.with(yourImageView).load("yourAssetFolder/yourGifImage.gif")
```